# storing different set of values under unique id in contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development

I need to store a set of values `eg: productprice,no of products customer bought, customer name` under unique `productId`. There can be any number of customers hence many set of values. If I create a srtucture

```
struct product{
  bytes12 productid;
  uint price;
  uint quantity
}
```

the values are overwritten.So I concatenated price,quantity and name to a single string and stored in an array.

```
struct Product{
  bytes32[] ProductArray; 
}

mapping(string =>  MapDetails) ProductStructs;

function appendDetails(string pid,bytes32 details) payable returns(bool success){
ProductStructs[pid].ProductArray.push(details);
}
```

`details` is a concatenated string holding price,quantity and customer name. Guess that's not the way of doing it. Can anyone direct me to proper way of storing them.Help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this here:

```
contract X {
    struct PRODUCT {
        bytes12 productid;
        uint price;
        uint quantity;
    }

    mapping (string => PRODUCT[]) products;

    function appendDetails(string pid, bytes12 productid, uint price, uint quantity) payable public {
        products[pid].push(PRODUCT(productid, price, quantity));
    }

    function getDetails(string pid, uint idx) 
    public view returns(bytes12 productid, uint price, uint quantity) {
        PRODUCT storage p = products[pid][idx];

        productid = p.productid;
        price = p.price;
        quantity = p.quantity;
    }

    function getDetailsCount(string pid) 
    public view returns(uint) {
        return products[pid].length;
    }
}
```

In the mapping you can map to an array, then you get exactly what you want.

Alternatively:

```
contract X {
    struct PRODUCT {
        uint price;
        uint quantity;
    }

    mapping (string => mapping (bytes12 /*productid*/ PRODUCT) ) products;

    function appendDetails(string pid, bytes12 productid, uint price, uint quantity) payable public {
        products[pid][productid].push(PRODUCT(price, quantity));
    }

    function getDetails(string pid, bytes12 productid) 
    public view returns(uint price, uint quantity) {
        PRODUCT storage p = products[pid][productid];

        price = p.price;
        quantity = p.quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...:)  This is exactly what I need...Can you explain 'idx' in getDetails function

Comment: your mapping is showing to an array. idx is the index (location) of the product in this array. Alternatively you could also write ``mapping (string => mapping (bytes12 /*productid*/ => PRODUCT)) products`` if you don't want to use arrays, but nested mappings.

Comment: Is it possible to get all set of values under pid?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not working yet in Solidity to return dynamically sized arrays. Hence you'll have to call getDetails multiple times. You can also add a method for fetching the size of the array -> ``return products[pid].length`` (see modified answer)